# Dúvida na composição de layout

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

#### Cenário teste

Gostaria de um layout basicamente conforme a imagem:

[image: tela]

O que já tenho é a "BARRA FIXA" e o "MENU DE ABAS".

---

#### Detalhes

Na imagem em exemplo, terei uma `table` na área verde e na área azul.

Sendo a área azul 40%, e área verde 60%, contando com suas áreas "título".

---

#### Dúvida

- Como posso fazer, para criar essa estrutura, sendo que as áreas devem ter essa proporção fixa 40%/60%?

  - Quando tiver mais registros que o tamanho aceito, deve ter a barra de rolagem (conforme os retângulos em roxo).

Comment: "criar uma tabela de registros", se são dados tabulares, `<table>` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Você diz, simplesmente criar uma table com tamanho fixo? Mas e depois as de baixo?

Comment: Os elementos HTML vão depender de quais são as informações que serão exibidas. Pela imagem não há como entender o que exatamente quer exibir. O problema está em criar a div, alinha-la ao layout ou exibir os dados? O título da pergunta também não ajudou muito ^^

Comment: Com as informações disponíveis eu diria que você consegue fazer isso de forma muito simples com `HTML`, `CSS` e `JavaScript`

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Mas eu queria saber o que usar para o html... Uso `div`, `frame`, etc para criar essa exibição da table, com o scroll lateral, mantendo o tamanho fixo na tela

Comment: O layout me parece bem simples, vc pode usar a semântica, chamando a div de header, mais, section e article, etc... mas basicamente seu layout são 6 div, sendo que a div azul tem uma altura fixa... Acredito que a barra fixa e as abas tb vão ter uma altura fixa apesar de vc não ter falado... E tb acredito que a tabela de registro deve ocupar 100% do espaço restante é isso? Se for isso considere incluir essas infos na pergunta, vai ajudar para te responder

Comment: Frame, nunca scroll lateral você pode aplicar em "qualquer" elemento no css `overflow-x: auto;`

Comment: Pergunta alterada.

Comment: @hugocsl Quase isso hugo. A questão é sobre como estruturar as 2 tables. Uma em cima da outra, mantendo proporção, e tendo a barra de rolagem na lateral... alterei toda pergunta, veja se melhorou

Comment: Mas qual exatamente a dúvida? Sobre a estrutura ou queres um template/exemplo html? A estrutura seria basicamente (vou usar nomes de classes para distinguir): `<header>><div class="header-barra-fixa"></div><nav class="header-menus"></nav></header><section class="tabela-a"><div class="tabela-a-titulo"></div><div class="tabela-a-conteudo"></div></section>
<section class="tabela-b"><div class="tabela-b-titulo"></div><div class="tabela-b-conteudo"></div></section>`

Comment: @RicardoPontual seria basicamente isso que disse. No caso então usaria section para exibir o conteúdo das tabelas. Mas dessa forma se tiver 200 registros na "tabela a", irá exibir inteira... o que queria é com barra de rolagem... eu vou alterar a imagem...

Comment: essa estrutura que sugeri é um base de layout. Podes colocar `overflow-y: auto` na classe `tabela-a-conteudo` e atingir isso. só pensei que deveria primeiro estruturar o layout e depois pensar no comporamento de cada parte em particular

Comment: "*- devem ter essa proporção fixa 40%/60%*" 40/60% de que? Do Viewport? Do que resta? Porque tem uma *BARRA FIXA* e um *MENU EM ABAS* fora esses dois elementos... Precisa ser com bootstrap?

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- Sim, estou usando bs4. as áreas azul e verde, proporção entre si é 40%/60%. as 2 áreas azul e verde somadas, proporção ao resto, seriam 70% e 30% os menus superiores.

Comment: É aceitável sem bootstrap? Barra fixa + menu = 30%, Registros = 70% (40/60%). Certo?!

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- na verdade a dúvida seria o final, mas como está muito confusa, eu estou pelo menos tentando enxergar sem BS, e depois me virar para aplicar com BS... até por causa dos grids, não sei se vai atrapalhar, se vou ter que criar classes extras, ou alterar algo do BS...

Comment: Em um contexto geral, você precisa de um layout seguindo a imagem postada. Depois de vários comentários, entendi que você quer "aprimorar" o que vc já tem pronto. Por que não postou o código que você já tem!? Já estava na metade do código pra te ajudar. Agora vou postar assim mesmo! ;X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou te propor uma solução tendo como base que a Barra Fixa, e div das Abas têm uma altura fixa, até pq não faria sentido elas terem uma altura variável, já que o conteúdo delas não é dinâmico. Partindo disso eu determinei que cada uma tem 50px de altua, mas vc pode por o tamanho que quiser, desde que "abata" essa altura das divs das tabela abaixo.

Então a base seria tipo assim

```
.bar,
.aba {
  height: 50px;
}
.t1 {
  max-height: calc(40% - 50px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.t2 {
  max-height: calc(60% - 50px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Eu usei o `max-height` para que caso o conteúdo da primeira tabela seja muito pequeno não vai ficar um espaço em branco entre ela e a tabela de baixo. No entanto quando o conteúdo da tabela 1 ultrapassar os 40% a barra de rolagem vai aparecer!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare na imagem que quando o conteúdo é pequeno ele ocupa apenas o tamanho necessário, porém quando cresce mais do que o que foi determinado aparecem as barras de rolagem.

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper [class^="col"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  flex: initial;
}

.bar,
.aba {
  height: 50px;
}
.t1 {
  max-height: calc(40% - 50px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.t2 {
  max-height: calc(60% - 50px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-100 wrapper">
    <div class="col-12 bar">Barra fixa</div>
    <div class="col-12 aba">Abas</div>
    <div class="col-12 t1"><table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr><tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></div>
    <div class="col-12 t2"><table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr><tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria assim:

**HTML / CSS**

```css
.um{
  height: 40%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.dois{
  height: 60%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow:auto;
}

.conteudo{
  height: 800px
}

.mytable{
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='conteudo'>
   <div class='um'>

   </div>
   <div class='dois'>
      <table class='mytable'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>test</th>
            <th>test2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>a</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: não dava pra melhorar a resposta e colocar um *snippet* aqui mostrando o funcionamento? ah, e sobre *deve ter a barra de rolagem*?

Comment: É isso aí... faltou só o `overflow: auto` na `um`. Mas basicamente é isso. Irei testar e retorno. Obrigado!

Comment: Agora fica a dúvida... Aplicando isso com BS4... Eu então deveria criar classe específica para essas div!? Porque o BS tem todo o esquema de grid dele... como ficaria !?

Comment: acredito que teria que fazer o css sim, visto que o `height` não funciona com % a não ser que a div anterior tenha um valor fixo em `height`! Na `div` _um e dois_ eu usaria `col-lg-12` e na `conteudo` usaria `row` alem dos css's que inseri na resposta

Answer (score 1):

> "*- áreas azul e verde, proporção entre si é 40%/60%. as 2 áreas azul e verde somadas, proporção ao resto, seriam 70% e 30% os menus superiores*"

Exemplo com HTML e CSS puro (**execute em tela cheia**):

```css
div.layout {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
div.layout > header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 15vh;
}
div.layout > nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 15vh;
}
div.layout > main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
}
div.layout > main > section > div.cabecalho {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 175, 200);
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
div.layout > main > section > div.cabecalho > h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
}
div.layout > main > section > div.cabecalho > nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
div.layout > main > section > div.registrosA {
    width: 100%;
    /*
     * REGRINHA DE 3...
     * 70 = 100
     * x = 40
     *
     * x = 28
     */
    height: calc(28vh - 30px);
    background-color: rgb(90, 130, 250);
    overflow: auto;
}
div.layout > main > section > div.registrosB {
    width: 100%;
    /*
     * REGRINHA DE 3 DE NOVO...
     * 70 = 100
     * x = 60
     *
     * x = 42
     */
    height: calc(42vh - 30px);
    background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Layout</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="layout">
            <header>
                BARRA FIXA
            </header>
            <nav>
                MENU EM ABAS
            </nav>
            <main>
                <section>
                    <div class="cabecalho">
                        <h2>TITULO</h2>
                        <nav>
                            <a href="#">Adicionar</a>
                            <a href="#">Atualizar</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="registrosA">
                        <p>REGISTROS A</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <div class="cabecalho">
                        <h2>TITULO</h2>
                        <nav>
                            <a href="#">Adicionar</a>
                            <a href="#">Atualizar</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="registrosB">
                        <p>REGISTROS B</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem velit recusandae cupiditate aut quas pariatur doloribus vero maiores nulla porro possimus accusamus expedita, quibusdam, aspernatur numquam perferendis a quod omnis?</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

O a barra fixa (topo) e o menu em abas ficaram um tanto grandes. Mas segue conforme pedido nos comentários da pergunta: tirei os 70% dos registros e os outros 30% dividi nessas duas barras...